Indefinite Simulation in Modelica
I would like to run a simulation until I tell it to stop i.e. run it without entering a specific stopTime. Does the Modelica language provide for this functionality and, if so, does a tool like OpenModelica Connection Editor have this capability?
I checked the Modelica Specification, but did not see anything regarding this topic.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The Modelica language does not prevent a tool from implementing such a feature, but there are no annotations to set up such an experiment from what I know.
In OMEdit, you can have a look at the interactive simulation option. It is not as well polished as simulating with a stop time but should be able to show you simulation results while simulating (the functionality is sometimes used for real-time simulations that never stop, but then usually with OPC-UA instead of the OMEdit GUI).

Another alternative is to generate FMUs and then run it forever using some FMU tool such as OMSimulator, FMPy or others.
